# Is it possible to call R source code function written in C directly in my C code?

Tags: c, r, fortran

I want to use function `nlminb` from `stats` package in my C program. I am aware of few different ways to do this: call R function within C code, using `Rcpp`.

But the function `nlminb` basically is written in Fortran and is wrapped in C code. One can find this code in `R-3.2.1/src/library/stats/src` files `portsrc.f`, `port.c` and `port.h`.

So is there a way to call functions in `port.c` or even in `portsrc.f` directly within my C code?

Answer (score 3):

Do you *have* to use `nlminb`? Note that the `optim` function does most of the same things as `nlminb`, and its entry points are documented in the "Writing R Extensions" manual.

> The interfaces (defined in header R_ext/Applic.h) are
>
> Nelder Mead:

```
void nmmin(int n, double *xin, double *x, double *Fmin, optimfn fn,
int *fail, double abstol, double intol, void *ex,
double alpha, double beta, double gamma, int trace,
int *fncount, int maxit);
```

> BFGS:

```
void vmmin(int n, double *x, double *Fmin,
optimfn fn, optimgr gr, int maxit, int trace,
int *mask, double abstol, double reltol, int nREPORT,
void *ex, int *fncount, int *grcount, int *fail);
```

> Conjugate gradients:

```
void cgmin(int n, double *xin, double *x, double *Fmin,
optimfn fn, optimgr gr, int *fail, double abstol,
double intol, void *ex, int type, int trace,
int *fncount, int *grcount, int maxit);
```

> Limited-memory BFGS with bounds:

```
void lbfgsb(int n, int lmm, double *x, double *lower,
double *upper, int *nbd, double *Fmin, optimfn fn,
optimgr gr, int *fail, void *ex, double factr,
double pgtol, int *fncount, int *grcount,
int maxit, char *msg, int trace, int nREPORT);
```

> Simulated annealing:

```
void samin(int n, double *x, double *Fmin, optimfn fn, int maxit,
int tmax, double temp, int trace, void *ex);
```

Comment: Yes I need to use `nlminb`.